# Repeated measure two-way ANOVA (non-parametric)

Tags: r, anova, repeated-measures, nonparametric, kruskal-wallis-test

Non-parametric ANOVA – a hot topic that is unanswered.

There are many questions on this topic online. However, they all seem to end in a debate and no definite answer or clear explanation (that I can relate to my data set). The only good answers I can find seem to relate to one treatment, that was repeated over time. How do I handle two treatments? More importantly, should this be handled as a linear model?

I cannot meet assumptions of homogeneity, normality, equal sample size, and transformations were not helpful.

Data setup:

- Soil cores growing plants.
- Subject – about 33 samples. A core will consist of a treatment combo (*n* = 5 to 6; repeats)
- `Treatment01` - clay, sand, loamy sand
- `Treatment02` - water, fertiliser
- Time - an sample is analysed from each core sample, every week, for 3 months.
- Variable - Nutrients (mg/kg soil), moisture, pH, mass of soil etc. For simplicity, let's do carbon.

Here are my failed attempts on R. This problem rests in the statistical theory.

`Anova(lm(Carbon ~ Treatment01 * Treatment02, data), type = "3")`
or
`model1 <- lm(Carbon ~ Treatment01 * Treatment02)`

Then something like...

```
print(lsmeans(model1, list(pairwise ~ Treatment01)), adjust = c("tukey"))
print(lsmeans(model1, list(pairwise ~ Treatment02)), adjust = c("tukey"))
print(lsmeans(model1, list(pairwise ~ Treatment01 | Treatment02)), adjust = c("tukey"))
print(lsmeans(model1, list(pairwise ~ Treatment02 | Treatment01)), adjust = c("tukey"))
```

Any suggestions? What are the disadvantages in pulling the data set apart to do a series of Friedman or Kruskal–Wallis tests (depending on how much I pull this data set apart?)

Comment: There's very little information here to go by. How about showing us the data (in a figure), and perhaps summary of results?